# My squares won't display php on a background?

Tags: php, class, object

I fixed a few things but nothing is still displaying on screen just blank no errors no nothing.
Does it have something to do with how I am returning the drawing?
Ran it in terminal on Linux Mint 13 and it came with this problem first `header ('Content-type: image/png');` so the placement maybe? Should this be with the return statement? Should I make a file instead using an include or require for the introduction of the new squares?

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: image/png');

class Shape {

private $size = 0;

public function __construct() {
  $foregroundRhex = substr($foregroundhex,0,2);
  $foregroundGhex = substr($foregroundhex,2,2);
  $foregroundBhex = substr($foregroundhex,4,2);

  $foregroundRed = hexdec($foregroundRhex);
  $foregroundGreen = hexdec($foregroundGhex);
  $foregroundBlue = hexdec($foregroundBhex);

  $foregroundcolor = imagecolorallocate($canvas, $foregroundRed,$foregroundGreen,        $foregroundBlue);
  $backgroundcolor = imagecolorallocate($canvas, $backgroundRed, $backgroundGreen, $backgroundBlue);
}

function draw(){
return 
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size) or die('Cannot Initialize the Image Stream Yoh!');
    $correctpos = ($size - $position);
    imagerectangle($canvas, $correctpos, $correctpos, $length, $length, $foregroundcolor);
    imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $backgroundcolor); 
    imagepng($canvas);
    imagedestroy($canvas);
 }
}
class Square extends Shape {

function __construct($x, $y) {
    $this->size = $x;
    $this->size = $y;
}

function draw() {
    return 
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size) or die('Cannot Initialize the Image Stream Yoh!');
    $correctpos = ($size - $position);
    imagerectangle($canvas, $correctpos, $correctpos, $length, $length, $foregroundcolor);
    imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $backgroundcolor); 
    imagepng($canvas);
    imagedestroy($canvas);
 }
}

$shapes = array(
new Square(150, '000099', 'ff0000', 5, 25), 
new Square(150, '009900', 'ff0000', 4, 19)
);

?>
```

Comment: `$shapes = array(
new Square(150, '000099', 'ff0000', 5, 25), 
new Square((150, '009900', 'ff0000', 4, 19);)
);`
Needs to be:

`$shapes = array(
new Square(150, '000099', 'ff0000', 5, 25), 
new Square(150, '009900', 'ff0000', 4, 19)
);`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because a class may contain only property and method definitions. So what you need to do in this case, is enclose all that code in a method (probably the constructor) like so:

```
class Shape {
   private $size = 0;

   public function __construct() {
      $foregroundRhex = substr($foregroundhex,0,2);
      $foregroundGhex = substr($foregroundhex,2,2);
      $foregroundBhex = substr($foregroundhex,4,2);

      $foregroundRed = hexdec($foregroundRhex);
      $foregroundGreen = hexdec($foregroundGhex);
      $foregroundBlue = hexdec($foregroundBhex);

      $foregroundcolor = imagecolorallocate($canvas, $foregroundRed,$foregroundGreen,        $foregroundBlue);
      $backgroundcolor = imagecolorallocate($canvas, $backgroundRed, $backgroundGreen, $backgroundBlue);
   }

   function draw();
   }
}
```

You simply can't have executable code inside a class which is not either part of a method (function) or the definition of a property (variable). If you thought you were just defining properties: you can only define compile-time constant values as property defaults. If you want more dynamic values (ie. substrings, etc.), you'll need to define it inside a __construct()'or.

Answer (score 0):

$foregroundRhex = substr($foregroundhex,0,2);
This and the 7 lines following it need to be inside a function (method) or a constructor.  The space they're in now is only for class-scope declarations.